# Keypress in javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, internet-explorer, keypress

I have a Flex application. It running in a player on the HTML-page. I need catch the key press events and prevent IE browser from acting like it wants. Here's some code:

Actually, the part where player was layed ..

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body scroll="no" onkeydown=keypress(event)>
<noscript>
    <object id="app" width="100%" height="100%" onkeydown="keypress(event)" onkeypress="keypress(event)">
        //some params
    </object>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the one, where I'm trying in a different ways to catch key input:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

        function keypress(e) {
            alert("Hello from keypress");
        }

        function init() {
            //index
            alert("Init!!!");
            document.getElementById('app').onkeydown = function() {
                alert("Key Pressed - 1");
            };
            document.onkeydown = function() {
                alert("Key Pressed - 2");
            };

            document.getElementById('app').onkeypress = function() {
                alert("Key Pressed - 3")
            };

            document.onkeypress = function() {
                alert("Key Pressed - 4")
            };

            window.onkeydown = function() {
                alert("Key Pressed - 5");
            };
            window.onkeypress = function() {
                alert("Key Pressed - 6");
            };

            document.body.onkeypress = function() {
                alert("Key Pressed - 7")
            };

            document.body.onkeydown = function() {
                alert("Key Pressed - 8")
            };

            if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener('keypress', keypress, false);
            } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                window.attachEvent('onkeypress', keypress);
            } else {
                window.onkeypress = keypress;
            }
        }


        window.onload = init;
        document.onload = init;
    </script>
```

I wasn't going to use them all together, just gathered them all to show you that I've tried almost everything (also including all this with 1 parameter).

**The problem is** that the only Alert I'm getting is "Init!!!". What's wrong with it or what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I get the "Init" message before the player loads it's content .. maybe the problem is somewhere there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Internet Explorer, events that occur within an embedded control in the `<object>` element do not fire equivalent events on the DOM object.  They are consumed by the embedded control, and it is that control's responsibility to handle them accordingly.

This means, when your embedded Flex application is focussed, your JavaScript code will not be able to handle any key events.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, if I understand you correctly, if I have only 1 object on my page (especially if it's '<object>'), the focus is tend to be setted at it (even if I don't do that explicitly) and there's no chance to prevent browser from living it's own life? The words you say are perfectly fit e.g. Firefox browser .. same application in FF is showing the desired behavior, but IE is making life more "interesting" .. as usual :)

Comment: @Antenka: yes, it's possible that the `<object>` element will receive focus when the page loads.  You might also find browsers other than IE that will not receive the key and mouse events from the embedded application.

Comment: Hmm .. is there any workaround to control this? Just, the thoughts that I have (e.g. a hidden something with a focus) not really great one, cause taking out focus from the main application don't really look like a good practice .. or I just should let it go and let the browser hot-keys alone?

Comment: @Antenka: if you have control over the application, you could fire them on the host element using the `fireEvent` method (IE only).  It would go something like this: `User presses key -> key event fires in embedded app -> embedded app fires key event on <object> element`.

Comment: Sorry for delay in responce .. was applying a few approaches :) Seems like the last suggestion was just duplicating the event in a browser, but wont let me prevent it. That's sad, fair enough .. marking the question as answered :) Thanks for your time.